# Can we calculate real time memory and storage utilization for ESXi host using Ansible Module?

Tags: ansible, esxi

I need to calculate the real-time memory and datastore utilization of an ESXi. Registering ansible facts captures the data once and does not change. The captured data needs to be for a conditional loop hence the utilization needs to be checked after loop execution. Is this achievable using Ansible?

Answer (score 0):

For a real-time memory utilization you may want to use nagios or other monitoring tools.
If you use ansible you will only get a snapshot at the time you ran the playbook.
Here is an example.

```
---
- name: cluster usage
  hosts: vcenter
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: Gather cluster info from given datacenter
    vmware_host_facts:
      hostname: 10.10.10.20  (should be the IP address of your ESXi server)
      username: username
      password: verysecretpass
      validate_certs: False
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: esxis

  - set_fact: 
      esxifacts: "{{ esxis.ansible_facts }}"

  - debug:
      var: esxifacts.ansible_datastore

  - debug:
      msg: "Free Memory available on {{esxifacts.ansible_hostname }} = {{ (esxifacts.ansible_memfree_mb * 100 / esxifacts.ansible_memtotal_mb)|int }}%"
```

Output will be:

```
 TASK [debug]  ok: [vcenter] => {
     "esxifacts.ansible_datastore": [
         {
             "free": "266.69 GB", 
             "name": "datastore1", 
             "total": "271.75 GB"
         }, 
         {
             "free": "34.89 TB", 
             "name": "datastore_main", 
             "total": "45.85 TB"
         }, 

     ] }
 
 TASK [debug]  ok: [vcenter] => {
     "msg": "Free Memory available on ESXi-01 = 8%" }
```

Comment: Using memfree_mb gives you the wrong percentage, because (at least on macOS and linux) it doesn't include the cache. Instead use `ansible_memory_mb.nocache.free` if it's available. See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/8035 for more context